# Quickbooks Desktop C# Integration

Tags: quickbooks

I am new to Quickbooks and given task of integrating Quickbooks desktop and web application(c#) via webconnector.I have written Webservice and communicated between Quickbooks and web application throught qbfc and qbxml.My doubts are,

1. Whenever a record is updated/inserted say for eg.Customer data ,I need it to be updated automatically to my webapplication..Is that possible?
2. How will I know that record is updated/inserted ?

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever a record is updated/inserted say for eg.Customer data ,I need
>   it to be updated automatically to my webapplication..Is that possible?

Yes.

> How will I know that record is updated/inserted ?

Query QuickBooks by the TimeModified timestamp. That will give you a list of objects that have changed since the given date/time.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need one way integration ie. Whenever a new customer is created in Quickbooks add it to your database, then you can either write a windows service or a scheduled exe that runs every x minutes and updates the data.